# iOS UIAutomation Failed:The target application appears to have died

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I occasionally got this failure message "The target application appears to have died" from iOS UIAutomation, i tried to dig out the root cause, but after lots of trying, still could not be able to find it, does anybody have this same problem as i do?

Comment: Maybe your application is *really* crashed?

Comment: Hi MrTJ, yes, i found out the problem, it was indeed crashed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Double check whether your application is not crashed due to some programming bug, low-memory condition or other reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have selected older version of the IOS simulator - for example 4.3.2 while your app is targetting 5.0 SDK.

Comment: Hi mlepicki, i actually profiled the connected ipad2 device, not using simulator.